# Work with loaded object name in R

Tags: r, object, naming

I'm trying to load each data set in a folder into R, run it through a function, store the output in a list, then remove it before going on to the next one.

```
datNames <- list.files(path = "/Some/Path/", pattern = "dl2*")
storeList <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(datNames)
for (i in 1:length(datNames) {
  load(file = paste0("/Some/Path/", datNames[i]))
  storeList[[i]] <- foo(<Name of data here>)
  rm(<Name of data here>) }
```

So basically I want to do something like the above but I don't know what to put in for "Name of data here". Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest loading in a separate environment. Then deleting every object in that environment. See the code below for example although its for one file it can be generalized. It can also be easily fixed to loop through all the objects in the environment and store them in a list of lists if that is desired for .R files with more than one object.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
save(x, file = "env_example.R")
datEnv <- new.env()
datNames <- list.files(pattern = "env_example.R")
storeList <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(datNames))
for (i in 1:length(datNames)) {
  load(file = datNames[i], envir = datEnv)
  storeList[[i]] <- datEnv[[ls(datEnv)[1]]]
  rm(list = ls(envir=datEnv), envir = datEnv) 

}
```

Comment: Do I have this right: running new.env() makes everything loaded into the workspace after that point in datEnv instead of global, right? Which is why removing all objects in datEnv will not destroy any functions or other objects that were living in the global environment before new.env()?

Comment: Almost, in my code above I created a new environment named datEnv. In the example above, I explicitly load objects into that environment. It is not that everything loaded into the workspace after that point is in datEnv. Please try this example: `datEnv <- new.env(); ls(datEnv); ls(); datEnv$x <- 2; z <- 1; ls(datEnv); ls()`. If I do not explicitly put objects into that environment they will still go into the global environment. Which is why z is in the global environment but x is not. Hadley Wickham has a great tutorial on environments: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html